# Creating a user in openedx by REST api (or anything else then traditional method)

Tags: mysql, rest, openedx

I need to create users in Open edX and sign them in via an API call, and thus do all the API stuff. What the major idea here is to create a one log in system where my user can log into this software we have and thus browse all the courseware and attend classes and track his data through software. The interaction between course and the software will be done by the REST API.

Is copying his identity into the valid table/database of the openedx do the job, but it still won't solve the online problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment in Open edX, as there is no API to create users. See the [list of available APIs](http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-platform-api/en/latest/overview.html).

But it would not be too difficult to create an extra endpoint to create new users. To that end, I suggest you make use of the `UserProfileFactory` available in `students.tests.factories`: https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/blob/master/common/djangoapps/student/tests/factories.py#L39

It's a factory used for testing but that can also be used in production -- it's a dirty hack, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

It possible to create/register user in Open edX using the REST API.

Send POST method to this url: `youredxdomain.com/user_api/v1/account/registration/`

Send the method to body using form-data.

In the url above you will get field in json like this

```
{
restrictions: {
min_length: 3,
max_length: 254
},
required: true,
name: "email",
errorMessages: { },
placeholder: "username@domain.com",
defaultValue: "",
instructions: "",
type: "email",
label: "Email"
},
```

When you send POST method to this url make sure to set `key` based on value of `name` in the json, for example the code `key` of the json above is `email` and set `value` to your email. Do the same on other field.

Hope it help.

Comment: This soulution doesn't activate the user so its pretty much useless (for a lot of use cases)

Comment: @IvanCastellanos if you are looking to activate user automatically you can disable the email verification, he's asking for REST API

Comment: Yeah I'm also talking about REST API, because I need normal new users to have email verification just NOT for the ones that I create using the REST API